# How to rename an existing Layer in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new with my Adobe Illustrator Software, so I am inquiring if anyone knows how to rename an existing layer file with a shortcut key and how to do it.

I already done it with my Adobe Photoshop Tool and it is very convenient, I don't need to move my mouse and double click it just to rename the filename.
Now I want to do it in my other tools so I can work easily without a hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut for renaming existing layer, but you can create new Action with one simple step - rename existing layer and then assign a function key for this action.

Next time you press this function key it will open dialog with layer options.

How create action you can read  [adobe help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/automation-actions.html).